# Selenium 2 can't click on link in google results page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing Selenium 2 code that searches Google by some criteria, then clicks on one of the links in the results to load this link. These steps are repeated in a loop.

Sometimes everything is ok, but sometimes when Selenium driver clicks on the link, Firefox only redirects back to the results. The requested url was never opened. The error occurs randomly in the Firefox `HtmlUnitDriver` every single time.

Here is the code:

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://google.com");

//set the search engine criteria
engineSearchInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']"));
engineSearchInput.sendKeys(this.searchCriteria);

//submit to engine
engineSearchInput.submit();
WebElement link = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {
    @Override
    public WebElement apply(WebDriver d) {
        return d.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='" + searchUrl + "']"));
    }
});
link.click();
```

Comment: Where is `searchUrl` declared? Show us the code, please.

Comment: The searchUrl is url that I want to open from result pages. For example if I type the search criteria that will put my searchUrl into the first results then the code search for this url and click on this link that contains the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to resolve the problem.
After submitting to google I add  `Thread.sleep(1500)` and everything is OK now.

Comment: You should not need to use `Thread.Sleep`; Selenium has a `WebDriverWait` object that you can use to wait until a condition is satisfied (such as the web page title indicating that the page you're expecting has loaded).